# Shaky Bootstrap Modal With Nested Elements

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working with [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) and [Angular 6](https://angular.io/) .

I am trying to show [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/).

In the `app.component` there is no problem. But with nested elements it is shaky.

Here is the [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ue4kvs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fseason.component.ts).

It's happening when `<app-chapter>` is child of the `<li>` element.

As a requirement of the programming logic, content of the Chapter Modal and the button that opens Chapter Modal should be in `ChapterComponent`. As a requirement of the design, the button that opens Chapter Modal should be in the `<li>` element.

If this shaky modal is inevitable with `<li>` element. Where should I write the content of the Chapter Modal ?

And why this shaky events happening?

Comment: It is happening because of the `list-group-item`  class.